# Customize colors for each chart element

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I want to make a ColumnChart where I can customize the colors for each chart element. I tried this:

```
> data
Company      male    female
1          0.6018735 0.3981265
2          0.6771300 0.3228700
3          0.7558140 0.2441860

companycolors <- "[  '#790700' ,
                     '#fbceb9' , 
                     '#0d055b' , 
                     '#8c8aaf' , 
                     '#0c0835' , 
                       '#443f9a' ]"
require(googleVis)
gvisColumnChart( data, 
                    xvar = "Company", 
                    yvar = c("male", "female"), 
                    options = list(
                      colors = companycolors
                      )
                    )
```

But apparently it uses just the first two colours and repeats them for company two and three.
Is there a way to give a specific color to each chart element?

Comment: I don't think so. Google Vis thinks you have two series here, so you get two colours. How is the legend going to work with six colours? You'd have to label it Company 1/Male Company 1/Female and so on..

Comment: The Google Visualization API colors data by series (column in a DataTable).  In order to get multiple colors, you need to split the data into multiple series.  I'm not sure how you would go about doing that in r, but if it's any help, I have a demo for one way to do it in javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/zwPuU/